# Return value is coming back as undefined

Tags: javascript, adobe, return-value, adobe-illustrator, object-literal

I am trying to write a script for Illustrator that will read the color i need from the object and then fill the template with that color where it is needed. it keeps returning as undefined. I am pretty new to Javascript any ideas what I am doing wrong?

i have tried returning as `newCMYKColor[stockColor]` , `newCMYKColor[stockColors]` and returning `stockColor[newCMYKColor]`

```
convertRoofColorToCMYK = function(stockColor) {
  var newCMYKColor = new CMYKColor(),
    stockColors = {
      BlackPoly: [80, 72, 68, 100],
      LightBlue: [100, 43, 0, 30],
      DarkBluePoly: [95, 74, 7, 44],
      PurplePoly: [82, 98, 0, 12],
      GreenPoly: [90, 12, 95, 40],
      YellowPoly: [0, 19, 89, 0],
      EcruPoly: [6, 13, 41, 4],
      OrangePoly: [0, 73, 98, 0],
      RedPoly: [7, 100, 82, 26],
      GreyPoly: [10, 4, 4, 14],
      WhitePoly: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    };
  try {
    newCMYKColor.cyan = stockColors[stockColor][0];
    newCMYKColor.magenta = stockColors[stockColor][1];
    newCMYKColor.yellow = stockColors[stockColor][2];
    newCMYKColor.black = stockColors[stockColor][3];
  } catch (e) {
    newCMYKColor.cyan = 0;
    newCMYKColor.magenta = 0;
    newCMYKColor.yellow = 0;
    newCMYKColor.black = 0;
  }
  return newCMYKColor;
};

roofColorCMYK = convertRoofColorToCMYK(Clipboard.roof_color);

if (!roofColorCMYK == undefined) {
  if (app.activeDocument.Layers["Tent Pieces"] &&
    app.activeDocument.Layers["Tent Pieces"].Layers["Roof Composite"]) {
    for (i = 0; i < app.activeDocument.Layers["Tent Pieces"].Layers["Roof Composite"].pathItems.length; i++) {
      app.activeDocument.Layers["Tent Pieces"].Layers["Roof Composite"].pathItems[i].fillColor = roofColorCMYK;
    } else {
      alert("sorry we are not able to fill the tent roof with the " +
        Clipboard.roof_color + " color.")
    }
```

before I added the else/if statement, it was telling me undefined at   `if (app.activeDocument.Layers["Tent Pieces"] && app.activeDocument.Layers["Tent Pieces"].Layers["Roof Composite"])`. After adding the else/if statement, it is giving me the alert every time.

Comment: I think this `!roofColorCMYK == undefined` (not the *!*) condition will never be `true` beacuse you are converting your value to a truthy or falsy value. And `convertRoofColorToCMYK ` will never return undefined beacuse you always return a value.Could you log the value of `roofColorCMYK`?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at MDN specification for try catch block. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch.

You have to remember that no code will be executed after a try catch block.

I suggest you to change your code this way :

```
try {
    newCMYKColor.cyan = stockColors[stockColor][0];
    newCMYKColor.magenta = stockColors[stockColor][1];
    newCMYKColor.yellow = stockColors[stockColor][2];
    newCMYKColor.black = stockColors[stockColor][3];

    return newCMYKColor;
  } catch (e) {
    newCMYKColor.cyan = 0;
    newCMYKColor.magenta = 0;
    newCMYKColor.yellow = 0;
    newCMYKColor.black = 0;

    return newCMYKColor;
  }
```

or use a finally block at the end (code inside finally is always executed what ever happens before).

```
try {
    newCMYKColor.cyan = stockColors[stockColor][0];
    newCMYKColor.magenta = stockColors[stockColor][1];
    newCMYKColor.yellow = stockColors[stockColor][2];
    newCMYKColor.black = stockColors[stockColor][3];
  } catch (e) {
    newCMYKColor.cyan = 0;
    newCMYKColor.magenta = 0;
    newCMYKColor.yellow = 0;
    newCMYKColor.black = 0;
  } finaly {
    return newCMYKColor;
  }
```

Comment: that seemed to work! its not giving me an undefined value anymore, but i think my Layers might just be the problem now. thanks!

Comment: Can you specify any resource where says this _You have to remember that no code will be executed after a try catch block._? Its not correct

Comment: @ajuni880 this is what i understand when i read this MDN [paragraphe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#The_finally_clause).
_It may seem strange to have a special exception-related clause that executes regardless of whether there is an exception, but this construct actually does serve a purpose. The important point is not that the finally-clause always executes, but rather that ordinary code following a try...catch does not._